# 2 heroku apps share database and are not syncing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have 2 apps that use the same database through the [heroku database sharing tool](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#sharing-heroku-postgres-between-applications).  I noticed a client was being served data that somehow existed in only 1 of the 2 databases.  When I say 2 databases, I mean the data that is accessible by running `heroku run rails c` from each app respectively.

**App 1:**

```
> pp c.weigh_ins.pluck(:id, :date, :current_weight)
D, [2018-10-16T14:47:43.016457 #4] DEBUG -- :    (30.4ms)  SELECT "weigh_ins"."id", "weigh_ins"."date", "weigh_ins"."current_weight" FROM "weigh_ins" WHERE "weigh_ins"."client_id" = $1  [["client_id", 19305]]
[[139358, Tue, 09 Oct 2018 00:00:00 EDT -04:00, 170.0],
 [138723, Tue, 02 Oct 2018 00:00:00 EDT -04:00, 217.2], # where does this come from?
 [138708, Tue, 02 Oct 2018 00:00:00 EDT -04:00, 174.6],
 [137962, Tue, 25 Sep 2018 00:00:00 EDT -04:00, 176.6],
 [137243, Tue, 18 Sep 2018 00:00:00 EDT -04:00, 175.8],
 [136489, Tue, 11 Sep 2018 00:00:00 EDT -04:00, 177.0],
 [135792, Tue, 04 Sep 2018 00:00:00 EDT -04:00, 178.8],
 [135217, Tue, 28 Aug 2018 00:00:00 EDT -04:00, 182.4],
 [134593, Tue, 21 Aug 2018 00:00:00 EDT -04:00, 184.2],
 [133950, Tue, 14 Aug 2018 00:00:00 EDT -04:00, 186.4],
 [133320, Tue, 07 Aug 2018 00:00:00 EDT -04:00, 188.8],
 [132630, Tue, 31 Jul 2018 00:00:00 EDT -04:00, 190.6],
 [132053, Fri, 20 Jul 2018 00:00:00 EDT -04:00, 194.4]]
```

**App 2:**

```
> pp c.weigh_ins.pluck(:id, :date, :current_weight)
   (15.8ms)  SELECT "weigh_ins"."id", "weigh_ins"."date", "weigh_ins"."current_weight" FROM "weigh_ins" INNER JOIN "check_ins" ON "weigh_ins"."check_in_id" = "check_ins"."id" WHERE "weigh_ins"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "check_ins"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "check_ins"."client_id" = $1  ORDER BY "check_ins"."week" DESC, "check_ins"."week" ASC  [["client_id", 19305]]
   (15.8ms)  SELECT "weigh_ins"."id", "weigh_ins"."date", "weigh_ins"."current_weight" FROM "weigh_ins" INNER JOIN "check_ins" ON "weigh_ins"."check_in_id" = "check_ins"."id" WHERE "weigh_ins"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "check_ins"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "check_ins"."client_id" = $1  ORDER BY "check_ins"."week" DESC, "check_ins"."week" ASC  [["client_id", 19305]]
[[139358, Tue, 09 Oct 2018 00:00:00 EDT -04:00, 170.0],
 [138708, Tue, 02 Oct 2018 00:00:00 EDT -04:00, 174.6],
 [137962, Tue, 25 Sep 2018 00:00:00 EDT -04:00, 176.6],
 [137243, Tue, 18 Sep 2018 00:00:00 EDT -04:00, 175.8],
 [136489, Tue, 11 Sep 2018 00:00:00 EDT -04:00, 177.0],
 [135792, Tue, 04 Sep 2018 00:00:00 EDT -04:00, 178.8],
 [135217, Tue, 28 Aug 2018 00:00:00 EDT -04:00, 182.4],
 [134593, Tue, 21 Aug 2018 00:00:00 EDT -04:00, 184.2],
 [133950, Tue, 14 Aug 2018 00:00:00 EDT -04:00, 186.4],
 [133320, Tue, 07 Aug 2018 00:00:00 EDT -04:00, 188.8],
 [132630, Tue, 31 Jul 2018 00:00:00 EDT -04:00, 190.6],
 [132053, Fri, 20 Jul 2018 00:00:00 EDT -04:00, 194.4]]
```

Since both apps have the same `DATABASE_URL` shouldn't they both access the same database?  Is there some way that they can be out of sync?  I realize they have different queries but they should return the same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queries in applications differ. Mainly, your first app does return deleted records since there are no conditions for `deleted_at IS NULL` (also the second one does an additional `INNER JOIN` which could filter out even more results). If you're using ActiveRecord models, you might have forgotten about a default scope in your first app.

Comment: ahhh I forgot the `deleted_at`!  Thank you!